# Trying to visualize a polygon in a space $X$

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, intuition, visualization

From Rotman's ***Algebraic Topology***:

> A **polygon** in a space $X$ is a $1$-chain $\pi = \sum\limits_{i=0}^k \sigma_i$ where $\sigma_i(e_1) = \sigma_i(e_0)$ for all $i$.
>
> By a theorem proven in the book, all polygons are $1$-cycles.

From the book: a $1$-cycle is essentially "a sum (union) of oriented $1$-simplices in $X$ that ought the constitute the boundary of some union of $2$-simplices in $X$."

But a polygon must have equal endpoints. So (as a simple example) is three disjoint circles in $\Bbb R^2$ considered a polygon? As in $\gamma = \sigma_1 + \sigma_2 + \sigma_3$ where each $\sigma_i \colon \Delta^1 \rightarrow \Bbb R^2$ is the $i$th circle.

Am I misunderstanding the idea or is there a simpler visual for this?

Comment: "But a polygon must have equal endpoints."  Why?

Comment: The second subscript should be $i+1$. And now it makes sense because $\sigma_i(e_1)=\sigma_{i+1}(e_0)$.

Comment: The definition in Rotman says $\sigma_i(e_1) = \sigma_{i+1}(e_0)$ where the indices are taken modulo $k+1$. This implies that the union of the images of these $1$-simplices is a closed loop (you can see it is a cycle directly from the formula for the boundary operator) and in particular is connected. Three disjoint circles is not a polygon because it is not connected, but it is a cycle. Not every cycle is a polygon, but you saw in your other question (math.stackexchange.com/questions/3587919/…) that every cycle is homologous to a linear combination of polygons

Comment: @William What does "the indices are taken modulo $k+1$" mean?  If the definition of a polygon is $\sigma_i (e_1) = \sigma_{i+1}(e_0)$ instead of $\sigma_i (e_1) = \sigma_{i}(e_0)$, then the proof of the theorem given immediately after the definition (a $1$-chain is a cycle iff it's homologous to a linear combination of polygons) must be wrong.

Comment: The proof says: To prove sufficiency let $\pi$ be a cycle, then $\partial \pi = \partial(\sum _i \sigma_i) = \sum (\sigma_i(e_1) - \sigma_i(e_0)) = 0$ by definition of a polygon.  If the definition is $\sigma_i (e_1) = \sigma_{i+1}(e_0)$ then how does this show that $\sum (\sigma_i (e_1) - \sigma_i(e_0)) = 0$.

Comment: By "taken modulo $k+1$" Rotman just means that $\sigma_k(e_1) = \sigma_0(e_0)$. The sum vanishes because it is telescoping: $\Sigma(\sigma_i(e_1) - \sigma_i(e_0)) = \sigma_0(e_1) - \sigma_0(e_0) + \sigma_1(e_1) - \sigma_1(e_0) + \dots + \sigma_k(e_1) - \sigma_k(e_0) $ and each $\sigma_i(e_1)$ cancels out $-\sigma_{i+1}(e_0)$. I will write up my comments into an answer, because they're getting a bit extensive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have made a transcription error when copying the definition of polygon. The definition Rotman gives (at least by the 4th corrected printing, 1998) says

> A polygon in a space $X$ is a $1$-chain $\pi = \sum_{i=0}^k \sigma_i$, where $\sigma_i(e_1) = \sigma_{i+1}(e_0)$ for all $i$ (indices are read mod$(k + 1)$).

In other words, the end of $\sigma_i$ is the start of $\sigma_{i+1}$. By "indices are read mod$(k+1)$" Rotman just means that $\sigma_k(e_1) = \sigma_0(e_0)$. Intuitively this should remind you of a cycle in a graph.

Rotman's proof that a polygon is a cycle is terse, and he doesn't mention that the sum is telescoping. Specifically I mean

$$\begin{align}
\partial \pi &= \sum_{i=0}^k \partial\sigma_i\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^k(\sigma_i(e_1) - \sigma_i(e_0))\\
&=\sigma_0(e_1) - \sigma_0(e_0) + \sigma_1(e_1) - \sigma_1(e_0) + \dots + \sigma_k(e_1) - \sigma_k(e_0)\\
&=(\sigma_0(e_1) - \sigma_1(e_0)) + (\sigma_1(e_1) - \sigma_2(e_0)) + \dots + (\sigma_k(e_1) - \sigma_0(e_0))\\
&= 0
\end{align}$$

The definition of polygon implies that $\cup_i im(\sigma_i)$ is connected, and therefore three disjoint circles is not a polygon.

Comment: Ah, that definition makes more sense now.  The definition given in the book I have must be a print error.  Intuitively a polygon is just some sequence of connected paths in a space, which coincides with the usual image of what a polygon is.

Comment: I just checked the front of the version I was looking at, apparently it's the 4th corrected printing :p So yes, it's possible the definition in your book has a typo.